# Rename the root module of my project in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, module

I want to rename the root module of my java project, however I'm getting an error "Can't rename root module". I'm using Intellij Idea 2019.3.2.
I'm also using gradle as the build tool.

Comment: try renaming directory and and add same name in setting.gradle and finally try reimporting project

Answer (score 36):

You can rename the root module of your java project, following these steps:

Go to Project Structure (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`S`) → `Project Settings / Project → Project name:`
[image: Project name:]

Open the settings.gradle file and rename the rootProject.name
[image: rootProject.name]

Once done, delete the .idea folder from your root project folder, rename your project folder on your system and then restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with grandle.
But there ist a way that worked for me in IntelliJ:

File > Project Structure > Project > Project Name
(Alternative Strg-Shift-Alt-S) > Project > Project Name

Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the directory's name and restart idea.

Answer (score 0):

Close the project and rename files in .idea/modules, than you can also rename the root folder and just open it again.

Comment: spring with gradle needs to change in settings.gradle, this answer is not complete

Answer (score 0):

You need to update rootProject.name in the file settings.gradle.kts if it's a kotlin gradle project. Otherwise the corresponding files in maven projects.